# Не работает rewrite в nginx

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, php-fpm

Здравствуйте, установил ubuntu 14.04, проблема в веб сервер nginx, загружаю сайт все нормально, но при переходе на какую либо страницу получаю в браузере ошибку File not found.

логи:

```
2014/07/10 23:38:53 [error] 7801#0: *14 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: $host, request: "GET /web/index.php/frontend/default/about HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "test.loc", referrer: "http://test.loc/web/index.php"
```

Nginx конфиг

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name $host;
    root /home/dogmar/www/$host;
    index index.php;

    charset        utf-8;

    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php break;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires 1y;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Как побороть? Необходимые права для чтения и записи выставлял.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. "FastCGI sent in stderr" говорит на о том, что дело в вашем приложении, а не в nginx.
2. Вместо вашего реврайта нужно использовать [try_files](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files).